# How to separate different folders changes under the same git repository?

Tags: javascript, git, github, architecture

I need a bit of professional advice for our big project (currently running).
To be more clear, I will describe the situation in detail and provide some more information about the problems we are facing.

Let's consider this situation.
Our project has a main folder where we initialized our git.It looks this way

```
main-folder/
|___ .git
 ___ .gitignore
 ___ package.json
 ___ other-files
 ___ oter-folders
 ___ ProjectName
    |___ FrontendFolder/
         |___ FrontendStaff
     ___ BackendFiles
     ___ BackendFiles
     ___ BackendFiles
```

To clarify, we have one repository for both backend and frontend.
We have one main branch - `master`, and `staging` for deployment. Both frontend and backend devs open their feature branches from `master` and deploy it by merging it into `staging`. The problem here is that we are facing merge conflicts not related to our job. So for example, frontend devs can't solve merge conflicts in backend files and actually they should not do it, which causes many problems during development. My question is that is there any possible way to solve this situation, where frontend devs will not face backend merge conflict, but at the same time, keeping this file structure and 1 main repository.
I have read about `git submodules`, but seems they are not the right solution for this situation, as you can't access parent repo's branches inside the submodule.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing. Many people work with multiple projects within a mono-repo. Git will not give you merge conflicts with stuff you did not touch. But your description of branching from master and merge into staging sounds wired to me, could you explain more about this, what is happening further with staging and when?

Comment: When you say "deploy it by merging *it* into `staging`", what is *it* -- `master`, or the feature branch? Merging the feature branch directly into staging could be problematic, but merging back into master and then master into staging should not ever cause merge conflicts that don't involve files the merger has changed, assuming everyone is following this procedure correctly.